# Ansible IOS_interface playbook results always changed=true

Tags: ansible

I'm running the below playbook. It's an ansible home lab from Chapter 2 of the Network Automation Cookbook. The 'P1T3 Interface Config' task always returns as changed=true even though I confirmed that the configuration was added to the routers and switches correctly.  The access switch in the output (access02) is virtual : Cisco IOS Software, vios_l2 Software (vios_l2-ADVENTERPRISEK9-M), Version 15.2. There are four total switches in the lab in all. This is the output of one as an example.

pb_network_build.yml

```
---
- name: "PLAY 1: Configure All Lan Switches"
  hosts: lan
  tags: lan
  connection: network_cli
  tasks:
    - name: "P1T3: Interface Config"
      ios_interface:
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        description: "{{ item.description }}"
        duplex: "{{ intf_duplex }}"
        mtu: "{{ intf_mtu }}"
        state: up
      loop: "{{ interfaces[inventory_hostname] }}"
      register: ios_intf
```

/etc/ansible/hosts

```
[access]
 access01 Ansible_host=172.16.2.18
 access02 Ansible_host=172.16.2.19


[core]
 core01 Ansible_host=172.16.2.20
 core02 Ansible_host=172.16.2.21

[wan]
 wan01 Ansible_host=172.16.2.22
 wan02 Ansible_host=172.16.2.23

[lan:children]
 access
 core


[network:children]
 lan
 wan
```

group_vars/network.yml

```
ansible_connection: network_cli
ansible_user: lab
ansible_password: lab123
ansible_become: yes
ansible_become_password: admin123
ansible_become_method: enable

intf_duplex: full
intf_mtu: 1500

domain_name: rohmanawslab.net
name_servers:
- 192.168.1.140
ntp_server: 192.168.1.140
```

group_vars/lan.yml

```
vlans:
  - name: Data
    vlan_id: 100
  - name: Voice
    vlan_id: 20
  - name: Web
    vlan_id: 40
  - name: Data30
    vlan_id: 30

interfaces:
  core01:
    - name: GigabitEthernet0/1
      description: core02_Gi0/1
      mode: trunk
    - name: GigabitEthernet0/3
      description: access02_Gi0/2
      mode: trunk
    - name: GigabitEthernet1/0
      description: access01_Gi0/2
      mode: trunk
  core02:
    - name: GigabitEthernet0/1
      description: core01_Gi0/1
      mode: trunk
    - name: GigabitEthernet0/3
      description: access02_Gi0/1
      mode: trunk
    - name: GigabitEthernet1/0
      description: access01_gi0/1
      mode: trunk
  access01:
    - name: GigabitEthernet0/1
      description: core02_gi1/0
      mode: trunk
    - name: GigabitEthernet0/2
      description: core01_e0/1
      mode: trunk
    - name: GigabitEthernet0/3
      description: Data_vlan
      mode: access
      vlan: 100
  access02:
    - name: GigabitEthernet0/1
      description: core02_Gi0/3
      mode: trunk
    - name: GigabitEthernet0/2
      description: core01_Gi0/3
      mode: trunk
    - name: GigabitEthernet0/3
      description: Web_vlan
      mode: access
      vlan: 40
```

$ ansible-playbook pb_build_network.yml --tags lan -vvv

output from a access02 interface:

```
changed: [access02] => (item={'name': 'GigabitEthernet0/3', 'description': 'Web_vlan', 'mode': 'access', 'vlan': 40}) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": true,
    "commands": [
        "interface GigabitEthernet0/3",
        "mtu 1500"
    ],
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "aggregate": null,
            "auth_pass": null,
            "authorize": null,
            "delay": 10,
            "description": "Web_vlan",
            "duplex": "full",
            "enabled": true,
            "host": null,
            "mtu": "1500",
            "name": "GigabitEthernet0/3",
            "neighbors": null,
            "password": null,
            "port": null,
            "provider": null,
            "rx_rate": null,
            "speed": null,
            "ssh_keyfile": null,
            "state": "up",
            "timeout": null,
            "tx_rate": null,
            "username": null
        }
    },
    "item": {
        "description": "Web_vlan",
        "mode": "access",
        "name": "GigabitEthernet0/3",
        "vlan": 40
    },
    "warnings": [
        "The value 1500 (type int) in a string field was converted to '1500' (type string). If this does not look like what you expect, quote the entire value to ensure it does not change."
    ]
}
```

Does anybody know why it keeps returning changed=true instead of false (green)? Or where I should investigate. I'm new at Ansible and it's not the end of the world, but all of the other playbooks return as 'changed=false' if I rerun the playbook

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi mrohman welcome to SO. I would _guess_ you will want `mtu: "{{ intf_mtu | string }}"` in keeping with the very clear warning you received. Be aware that wrapping the expression in `"{{ ... }}"` does not automatically make it a `str`, it just protects the jinja2 mustaches from being interpreted as yaml `dict` syntax. Let us know if that `| string` helps

Comment: Thanks for your help mdaniel. I don't receive the warning (from above) since I've added the ` | string ` statement to the playbook.  Do you have any idea why the `changed: true ` doesn't change to ` false ` even though the configuration changes are made correctly? Thanks again.

Comment: You'll want to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67643977/edit) and show the updated output after fixing your playbook, since the comments are not a good vehicle for that content. If you are still experiencing `changed=true` even after the string coercion, then all I know is to run the appropriate `_info:` task to see what the state of affairs is before your change in order to compare it afterward. Computer are so picky!